# How to add time when use toggleClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#toggle-btn").click(function(){
    $(".example").toggleClass("with-text");
  });
});
```

How to add time to when toggleClass?
For example, any where I can add "5000" so it will add class in 5 seconds?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry what is the requirement... if clicked then in 5s the class to be added... but what should happen if clicked again in 5 secs

Comment: also if class is present then clicked when it should be removed immediately or after 5s

Comment: To delay you can use setTimeout()

Comment: How to have a slide effect if you add a class which move div?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout`

```
var timer = null;
$("#toggle-btn").click(function(){
  if(timer != null){
   clearTimeout(timer )
  }
  timer = setTimeout(function () { $(".example").toggleClass("with-text"); }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use setTimeout. Try the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#toggle-btn").click(function(){
    $("#toggle-btn").prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".example").toggleClass("with-text");
      $("#toggle-btn").prop('disabled', false);
     },5000);
    });
});
```

Edit: added disabled attribute so you can only click it if the timeout is over.

Answer (score 1):

just do like this. This creates a animation. So if you want the new text to fade in take this.

```
  $("#toggle-btn").click(function(){
    $(".example").toggleClass("red",5000);
  });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3cLjw399/)